# Why can't I set host name for action_mailer.default_url_options by Devise 3 and Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Some source of my config/environments/development.rb file

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.apne1.nitrousbox.com' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    port: 25,
    domain: 'http://myapp.apne1.nitrousbox.com',
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["MANDRILL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["MANDRILL_API_KEY"]
  }
```

The mail can send successfully.But the password reset link url likes:

```
https://users/password/edit?reset_password_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

The host url `myapp.apne1.nitrousbox.com` disappeared! And `http` became `https`.

I had search the internet and find someone has the same issue.Somebody have lucky and their settings worked.I have tried that but the same result.

---

Error log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
```

---

## Rails

4.1.0

## Devise

3.4.0

## Datetime

A.D.2014-11-02 00:00:00

---

## [Edited the last day]

The password reset link(as devise's default):

```
<%= link_to 'Change password', edit_password_path(@resource, reset_password_token: @token) %>
```

Comment: Please add the code for the password reset link!

Comment: Do you ave host as a environment variable

Comment: @Hemali Thank you. My environment has no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "myapp.apne1.nitrousbox.com"
```

In your `config/production.rb` file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried that, but the same result:(

Comment: I have find the reason.That's because of the subdomain!From the document of devise, I fix the issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Send-emails-from-subdomains